# Jenkins : Cannot instantiate class error when executing java testNG project

Tags: java, git, jenkins, command-line, devops

The aim is to clone my java project (which is using TestNG)from GitHub and execute the test from Jenkins using "Execute Windows batch command".

**Step 1) I am cloning the project from GitHub using ssh**

> "git clone -b master https://github.com/xxxxxx/QACODE.git"

**Step 2) Once clone is done there is a separate job for compiling and executing the project from TestNG file.**

> "cd C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test_automation\XXXProject"
>
> "java -cp C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test_automation\XXXProject\lib*;C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test_automation\XXXProject\bin org.testng.TestNG TestNG.xml

**Now I am getting the below error**

> [Test_automation] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson1958039333746041382.bat
>   [TestNG] [ERROR] 
>   Cannot instantiate class com.xxx.testcases.XxxTestCase
>   Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

I can find all class\java files in the cloned directory but still for some reason Jenkins not able to instantiate the class.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both the jobs are pointing to different location one is user app data and another jenkins home workspace, as you mentioned two separate jobs there workspace will be different

Comment: No Subrata I'm pointing to correct location actually before git clone i'll go cd C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test_automation then i'll clone

Comment: Can you please go to the directory where the code is there and run from command prompt and check if it running...